# String as resource file name

Tags: c#, resources

I'm not sure of the terminology here, but I need to access a specific resource file who's name is the string that is calculated.

For example:

I have a resource file named **"resFile-en-GB"** I can access a string inside by using **"resFile-en-GB.stringKey"**. Now I need to add the culture info to the end of a string.

```
string stringA = "resfile-";
string stringB = "en-GB";
string stringC = stringA + stringB;
```

Now I need to use **"stringC"** as the resource file name like **"stringC.stringKey"** How would I go about doing this?

Comment: are you just trying to introduce multi lingual to your application? because that is well supported in .net and you don't have to format the language resource names this way. but maybe you are after something more complicated that I don't understand

Comment: Yes, I am try to add multi-lingual support for my messages. I have already localized the form. I have been trying to ressearch how I am supposed to do it, but I cannot find what i am looking for. The best I can find is to use a resource file to store the translated messsages. As this is the only way I could think of doing it, I thout it was my easiest option. Maybe you can point me in a better direction?

Comment: Tried my best, hope it helps. If not, comment away, see below. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your application multi lingual with the use of resource files.

### Add the resource files to your solution

That's the obvious first step. For example add a folder to your solution `ResourceFiles` and add the resx files:

- LanguageStrings.resx
- LanguageStrings-fr-FR.resx
- LanguageStrings-nl-NL.resx

The LanguageStrings.resx will contain the `default` language, let's say english. The fr-FR will contain the French language and nl-NL the Dutch language. You can just add items to the resource files. For example HelloWorld = Hello world.

Right, so you added the HelloWorld key to your three language strings .resx files with the proper translations.

### Set the culture

Somewhere in your application you want to be able to set the language. It could be in some event handler (a listbox or whatever you thought up). There you want to set the chosen culture info on the `LanguageStrings`.

```
var cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nl-NL");
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
LanguageStrings.Culture = cultureInfo;
```

This sets the language hardcoded to the Dutch language. Obviously you want to make the "nl-NL" variable so that you can set the language to whatever language the user choose.

### Get your localized strings

Finally you want to retrieve the localized strings from the resources files. For example something like:

```
 label.Text = LanguageStrings.HelloWorld;
```

Here the magic happens. **You** don't have to define which language resource file should be used to retrieve the localized string. That is done *for* you because you already set the desired language to your resource file (`LanguageStrings.Culture = ..`).

That's the basics, I hope this helps you on your way.

Comment: Great reply there, thank you very much. I will try to follow right now.

Comment: I'll probably be asleep when you get back but hopefully I can read your success tomorrow morning :). Good luck!

Comment: I'm not sure how to set it to translate with this method. I did what you said and each time it's english. I have the files like you said with the keyword the same in all 3 files, but with translations in 2 and it's always english.

Comment: are you sure you are using the culture info's (nl-NL etc) correctly. There is a complete list here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: I was using the value "nl-NL" stored in a string, which I creat a new cultureInfo oject with. I will check the link thanks.

Comment: and the naming convention for the LanguageStrings-nl-NL.resx are also strict. Check MSDN for the naming conventions. The stuff I supplied in this answer work on my PC so it should work on yours too. It IS crucial that your code is executed that sets the CultureInfo = cultureInfo and CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo. Without that it will be defaulted to en-US. Now I really need to go to bed :). Will check up tomorrow morning

Comment: Thank you very much, I got it working thanks to your post. For reference I named it LanguageResource and  LanguageResource.nl then it worked fine.

Comment: Hmm bit weird though, should work with nl-NL too.  But if you got it too work: thats what counts. Msdn explains how the conventions work in more detail. Anyway glad it works! Good job. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

you can access resources via the [ResourceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx) and then use GetString(key), probably easier in this case:

```
var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(stringC, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
resourceValue = resourceManager.GetString(key);
```

Comment: Thanks alot that is it. I just have another problem now though. It needs to have a "_" under-score in the culture info not a "-" hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

[ResourceManager.GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d17ax2xk.aspx) method should help you achieving this.